# How to make Gradle use the newer version of a dependancy when two are declared

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, jackson, build.gradle

I want to use a newer version of `Jackson` instead of the one that is included in the spring boot.

I wrote the following `build.gradle` using `dependencyManagement`.

```
...
dependencyManagement {
   imports {
      mavenBom "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.5.12"
      mavenBom "com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.13.2"
   }
}
...
```

However, old version(included in the spring boot starter) still remains dependency.
[image]

Why is this happening? I only want to use the new version.

Answer (score 1):

Gradle will end up downloading multiple versions of the same dependency if distinct version are declared in two different places, but will only use one in runtime.

> Simply put, Gradle chooses the highest version encountered in your dependency graph

Quote from a [very good article](https://jlbp.dev/how-does-version-resolution-work-in-maven-and-gradle) that describes version resolution algorithms in a great detail.

So the fact that there are two versions are shown in the IDE should not be a problem.

In order to be absolutely sure that the latest version is used, you can print the resolved version with the following command

```
 ./gradlew dependencies | grep jackson
```